# how to reboot the remote server and wait for device to up again and execute another commands after reboot using paramiko python

Tags: python, pytest, paramiko

I had tried  the following code:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()        
client.load_system_host_keys() 

chan = client.get_transport().open_session(timeout=timeout)

chan.settimeout(timeout) 

chan.exec_command("/sbin/reboot -f > /dev/null 2>&1 &")
```

This code only make reboot to be executed in background and switch over to the another command after reboot.
But the requirement is remote server should rebooted and from client side the code should have wait till the remote server is up again and then execute the another commands after reboot statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like

```
while True:
    try:
        # your commands
        break
    except:
        sleep(some_timeout)
```

I would also recommend using `fabric`: it has some nice features, including retry parametes for commands. It also has `reboot` command in `fabric.api`.

Comment: OK Thanks.Can it be try using paramiko,i have to execute command 'ls' in remote server directory after reboot and wait event.

Comment: i had also try fabric reboot  but it does not wait or hang till the device come up again